# A Regex To Remove src Attributes With Dimensions In

Tags: c#, regex

This is probably a rather simple question to solve, butI'm trying to use a Regex on a string and have it remove any src attributes that contain dimensions, like this:

```
src="/some/path/here_000x000.jpg"
```

so

```
<img src="/some/path/here_000x000.jpg"/>
```

would become

```
<img />
```

after processing.

From researching I found that

```
\d{1,5}x\d{1,5}
```

finds dimensions, and

```
src\s*=\s*"(.+?)"
```

will find a src attribute, but how can I combine these both and have some simple c# code whereby all matching patterns in a given string are removed (ie. replaced with '')?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
src\s*=\s*"[^"]*?\d+x\d+.*?"
```

Technically, you shouldn't limit the digits to five (even though there shouldn't be a need for such).

This matches `src` (1), any number of spaces (2), `=` (3), any number of spaces (2), `"` (4), any number of any characters (except `"`) (non-greedily) (5), any positive number of digits (6), `x` (7), any positive number of digits (6), any number of any characters (except newline) (non-greedily) (8), and `"`(3).

1. `src`
2. `\s*`
3. `=`
4. `"`
5. `[^"]*?`
6. `\d+`
7. `x`
8. `.*?`

Comment: this would not work...`.*?` is ambigious..it can also match `\d+x\d+` in another `src` tag and then replace multiple src tags..

Comment: @Hode imagine an input `<img src="c:\sss.jpg"\><img src="c:\sds\ss232x445.jpg"\>`..here both tags would get replaced

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex

```
src\s*=\s*"[^"]*\d+x\d+[^"]*"
```

escape `"` with `""`

Comment: Can you give some sample C# using for example Regex.Replace so I can see how you are using this please

Comment: @HodeCode you can use `Regex.Replace(input,regex,replace)`..Replace method would return a new replaced string..

Comment: But how do you use it as a String in code, given that it has double quotes throughout it.

Comment: Have worked it out, thanks! I replaced the double quotes with single quotes after realising my data only contained single quotes around attribute values. Thanks for your help, have upvoted

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
src=".*?\d+x\d+\.\w+"
```

It will match 1 or more digits